# Some git tags not visible in gitk

Tags: git, gitk

In the gitk view, I notice some (but not all) git tags missing. `git tag` shows those tags, and I am also able to checkout by specifying those tags, so the tags got created correctly. What should I try to understand and debug this problem?

Comment: would those missing tags be on commits that already have some other, visible tag?

Comment: @eis No, those commits were tagged recently and for the first time. They have not been tagged with any other tag.

Comment: Does gitk show the commits associated with the tags? Note that without the `--all` parameter, gitk shows only parent commits of your current HEAD.

Comment: @helmbert When invoked with `--all`, it does show all the branches now. Thanks for the comment, it helped. Could you please post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without the `--all` parameter, gitk shows only parent commits of your current HEAD.
When calling gitk with this parameter, you should see the entire history with all commits (and all tags).

Comment: I just wish that --all could be my default.

Comment: If your're using Bash as shell, just put `alias gitk="gitk --all"` in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

## gitk <otherthings> --tags

#### gitk <otherthings> --tags=<pattern>

Example:

```
gitk --all --tags=save_201811*
```

shows me all my save_points this month.

With the `-all` option alone, gitk will not necessarily display all the tags.

I often tag the current state in git with something like `git tag save_20181123_1054`.
That way, if anything goes wrong with my `git rebase` I can restore the current state, and after rebasing I can verify (with `git diff save_20181123_1054`) that I have the same changes (i.e. working and tested software) but more logically organized.

After the `git rebase`, I have a nice branch with perfect fixes, but the save-tag is a hanging leaf on my tree of development.

Opening `gitk` a day or two later will not show these tagged hanging leaves, even if invoked with `gitk -all`.

`gitk --tags` is the solution but in practice you'll probably want --all too
or something else to avoid getting only the tags.

You might want to experiment with ...

```
gitk HEAD --tags
gitk <mybranch> --tags
gitk --all --tags
```